# When & How often do 4e Monster powers recharge?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters

How often should I roll power recharge rolls and at which point in the monster's turn do I re-roll them?

I'm trying to find the official definition of the recharge mechanic in the online compendium and I'm not seeing it there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You Roll Once per Turn, at the Start of the Monster's Turn**

Monster Manual glossary explains recharge:

> The power has a random chance of recharging during each round of combat. At the start of the monster’s turn, roll 1d6. If the roll is one of the die results shown, the power is recharged and the monster can use it again that turn. The power also recharges after a short rest.

You would roll it whenever you resolve the "start of turn" phase of each monster, at the same time, for example, as it takes ongoing damage. You roll once for each power that has been used; if the monster has not used the power, you do not roll to recharge it. You can't "bank" multiple charges.

I should note that in more recent publications (eg: Rules Compendium) the explanation was change from "start of the monster's turn" to "start of each of the monster's turns", clarifying that you do roll to recharge each turn for a monster that takes multiple turns in a round.