# What is recharge in 4e?

Tags: dnd-4e, published-adventures, terminology

I am a new dungeon master that is DMing for some of my friends that want to play but are beginners. I am turning an adventure called Khyber’s Quest, 4th edition, into a 5th edition game to play. Can someone tell me what recharge is? On encounter 5, there is a monster called Dolgaunt Acolyte that has an ability with recharge next to it. Maddening Whispers is the ability. This is what the ability looks like.

> Maddening Whispers (standard; recharge ⚃ ⚄ ⚅) 
>   Close blast 5; targets enemies; +5 vs. Will; 1d6 + 4 psychic
>   damage and the target slides 3 squares.

I know what all of this is, except for the recharge. If you have played Khyber’s Harvest or know what recharge is, thanks for the help.

Comment: [Related question is here.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/19144/22566)  This particular question [probably answers your question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/28229/22566). Please take a look.

Comment: You may be playing D&D 5e, but your question is about D&D 4e, so I changed the tags. I also added published-adventures (since you’re asking about something that shows up in one) and terminology (since you’re asking what a particular term means). If any of those was in error, please feel free to remove or change them. Thanks for the question, and welcome to the site.

Comment: Thanks for changing the tags KRyan. I also thank you for replying @KorvinStarmast. I know the information I needed to know. Thanks for the help.